# Browser says 'Waiting for xxxx.ru' in its status bar while loading my website. Is my site hacked?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, web

When I go to my website, the browser says 'Waiting for xxxx.ru' in its status bar while loading. I have no JavaScript (or any other) libraries pointing to this weird website. Does this mean my site is hacked? I checked the ".htaccess" file, and so far it seems to be OK. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Developer Tools with Chrome Browser to follow the requests in Network tab.

Edit > Developer > Developer Tools.

> If you are using Chrome try disable all plugins...